# How to send Automation Result mails from Testcomplete Jscript

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcomplete

I need to send automation Result to devlopers which is automatically from test complete is there any possibility method there

Comment: You should better ask this question on Test Complete support forums.

Answer (score 0):

In TestComplete 12.50, you can [send results via email](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/log/working-with/sending-via-email/about.html). The log of the entire test run or any of its children logs via:

1. Quick sending from the log context menu
2. Sending from scripts
3. Sending from keyword tests

Last two methods allow you to send, during the test execution.

> Result to developers which is automatically

Ideally the CI employed should provide you with a mechanism to support the reporting activity. Basically, in your case, you have to follow two steps:

1. Use methods of the [slPacker](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/program-objects/slpacker/index.html) object to pack the test results to a file (it is easier to manage a single file then a group of files). You can call these methods from a keyword test, for instance, via the Call Object Method operation. There is more details on how to pack results, in [Archiving results](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/log/working-with/compressing/from-tests.html) from tests.
2. Write script code that will send the test log. [JScript snippets here](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/sending-email-from-scripts.html).